# Why can QNetworkAccessManager queries prevent Qt applications from exiting?

Tags: c++, qt, qtnetwork

My Qt application that uses QNetworkAccessManager to access the internet won't exit after closing the main window if there is no working internet connection.

Sample application (tested with Qt 4.8, MSVC2010, Win7 x64):

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QMainWindow>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();
    QNetworkAccessManager * pManager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
    QNetworkReply * pReply = pManager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(
                                           "http://www.google.com")));
    pReply->abort();
    delete pReply;
    delete pManager;
    // If there is no internet connection, the application will stay alive
    // forever after closing the main window.
    return a.exec();
}
```

Am I missing something or is it a bug? If yes, what workaround do you suggest to make sure the application exits?

Edit:
I have to correct myself: The sample application only stays alive for about 13 seconds after closing the main window. It *would* stay alive forever if the QApplication object had been allocated using `new` (which is the case in my actual application).

Comment: Interesting, QNetworkAccessManager uses threads internally, which might have to do with it. Here two things differ from normal usage a) You use QNAM before an event loop is running and b) you delete the reply object right away before returning to the event loop. I wonder, does the issue also occur when using QNAM after a.exec() is called?

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld Yes, the issue also occurs if I put `a.exec()` just before the QNAM stuff. Assigning `QNetworkAccessManager::get` and `QNetworkReply::abort` to buttons on the main window does not change anything (which means neither a) nor b) is the cause).

Comment: If you put a.exec(), before the QNAM stuff, the situation is similar to the initial one: no event loop is running (anymore). But if you trigger it via the UI, there is one, so that would be the normal use case. I'd create a minimal test case and report it as Qt bug.

Comment: Interestingly it works fine under OS X ML with 4.8.1, it sounds like a platform specific bug. I'd definitely report it as a bug in that instance.

Comment: If I run the executable on a WinXP virtual machine there is no such delay either. But that doesn't mean it's Win7-specific. (For instance my network configuration might be somehow exceptional). I just can't imagine I'm the first one to use QNetworkAccessManager on a Win7 machine.